# Web Config Error in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, webforms

I have a web form that is hosted on my own PC's localost (IIS-Express).I am working with .NET 4.6.

In my web.config I have

```
<sectionGroup>
    <section>
      <applicationSettings>
        <UI.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name=" UI_Portal" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://localhost/Service/EppPortal.asmx</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="UI_Portal" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://localhost/Service/Portal.asmx</value>
          </setting>
        </UI.Properties.Settings>
      </applicationSettings>
      </section>
</sectionGroup>
```

And I get the error:

**`The configuration section 'sectionGroup' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration`**

**

```
Config Source:
  305: 
  306:   <sectionGroup>
  307:
```

**

I can't find a way to resolve it. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: your posted config code doesn't match the error description. post the actual code

Comment: Is there more to your web.config?  Do you use `<sectionGroup>` tags anywhere?

Comment: @Rahul sorry, i copied badly. plz see now.

Comment: @MADsc13nce yes there is sectionGroup, plz see. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there the error you are, you are missing the `<configSections>` element alltogether. It should be like below. See [sectionGroup Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309409(v=vs.71).aspx) for more information

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup>
    <section>
      <applicationSettings>
        <UI.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name=" UI_Portal" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://localhost/Service/EppPortal.asmx</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="UI_Portal" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://localhost/Service/Portal.asmx</value>
          </setting>
        </UI.Properties.Settings>
      </applicationSettings>
      </section>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Comment: No, I still get the error: The configuration section 'section' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration   when I do the other way around.

Comment: It shouldn't be. Can you post your web.config ... if not fully but the entire part where you define sections

Comment: I posted it -- all the section thing is there only. Even Ctrl+F says that my code has only 4 section tags.

Answer (score 0):

I have section group defined like this in my web config, have a look, if could be of any help.

```
 <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```